# SoapServer::SoapServer(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, web-services, yii, wsdl2php

i have exposed a couple of web services through Yii. After upgrading to PHP 5.6.33 from PHP 5.5.x, i face the following error

```
SoapServer::SoapServer(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

the error occurs on line 166 on framework/web/services/CWebService.php (1.1.19) so far i haven't found any work around, the options property is protected and don't know how to bypass this issue, but still http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php doesn't seem to support same options as SoapClient

```
            $options["stream_context"] = stream_context_create([ 
                "ssl" => [ 
                    // set some SSL/TLS specific options 
                    "verify_peer" => false, 
                    "verify_peer_name" => false, 
                    "allow_self_signed" => true 
                ]]);
```

Comment: It looks like there is no way to disable certificate validation for SoapServer in the same way as for SoapClient :-( This makes development more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up that it was a server configuration issue. The production servers didn't faced this issue since the certificate was signed from a known authority however in the private servers, we needed to edit the php.ini file

```
openssl.cafile = "/etc/path/to/pem/file.pem"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error too on Linux (Ubuntu) with PHP7.2 when I tried to create SoapServer in my development environment.
If you do not want to set the PHP *openssl.cafile* globally, just copy your Root CA into the correct folder and update certificates:

```
sudo cp my_root_ca.pem /usr/share/ca-certificates/my_root_ca.crt
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

While reconfigure ca-certificates you need to select your own certificate and activate it.
(If you do not need your Root CA anymore in your develop environment just reconfigure certificates again, unselect your CA from the list and finally update certificates.)